# hive - Regex in Split function not giving output. It is empty

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I want to split the string into four characters each using hive query.

Input :  `abcdefghijkl`

```
select split("abcdefghijkl", '([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})') from table limit 1;
```

Output is `["","","",""]`

Output required: `["abcd","efgh","ijkl"]`

Comment: Instead of split, check the matches.

Comment: Try `select split(regexp_replace("abcdefghijkl",'.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})',',$1'),',') as output;`. Probably, you will want the `(?<!^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3})([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})` regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It worked . Thanks

Comment: I posted, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
select split(regexp_replace("abcdefghijkl",'.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})',',$1'),',') as output;
```

The `.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})` pattern matches

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})` - Capturing group 1: 4 alphanumeric chars

The match is replaced with the `,` and the contents of Group 1. Then, `split` splits the result with a comma.